# Replace every occurrence of a string with the number of times it has occurred so far

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a string with placeholders and I want to attach an index to wach of the placeholders.

e.g.

```
'This @placeholder is @placeholder'
```

Should become

```
'This @param0 is @param1'
```

Assuming I have a list of params with 2 values(matches the number of time @placeholder occurs) .

One optional solution would be.

```
result = ''
parts = my_text.split('@placeholder')
for i in range(0, len(params)):
  result += '{}@param{}'.format(parts[i], i)
return result
```

Another option is to keep replacing the placeholder with the current index, but this means scanning the string len(params) times.

```
for i in range(0, len(params)):
  my_text = my_text.replace('@placeholder', '@param{}'.format(i), 1)
```

is there a better solution for doing this in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a simple `re.sub` solution with a callback and counter?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> c = itertools.count()
>>> text = 'This @placeholder is @placeholder'
>>> re.sub(r'\b@placeholder\b', lambda x: f'@param{next(c)}', text)
'This @param0 is @param1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer by @Ajax1234 I can just replace the place holder with {} and use formatting with an array.

```
my_text = 'This param{} is param{}'
print(my_text.format(i for i in range(len(params))]))
```